# getting error on flutter stripe card page

Tags: flutter, dart, stripe-payments, pubspec

> this error is getting if again trying to place booking via card form page ...But when try to bookig first time it is working fine..

> I am using Stripe Payment dependency flutter_stripe: ^3.0.2 with following source code for showing the card form , and unable to get form when doing booking second time , only Payment button showing

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ExampleScaffold(
      //title: 'Add New Card',
      //tags: ['No Webhook'],
      payButtonClicked:paybtnclicked,
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20,vertical: 25),
      children: [

        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0 , bottom: 10),
          child: Text("Add Your Card Information",
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                  fontSize: 20,
                  letterSpacing: 0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                  color: Color(0XFF000000))),
        ),
        CardFormField(
          controller: controller,
          style: CardFormStyle(
            // borderWidth: 1,
            //borderRadius: 20,
            borderColor: Colors.blueGrey,
            textColor: Colors.black,
            fontSize: 24,
            placeholderColor: const Color(0xFFE73E34),
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
          child: LoadingButton(
            onPressed:
            controller.details.complete == true ? _handlePayPress : null,
            text: 'Pay \$${widget.booking_data['total_price']/100}',
          ),
        ),        
      ],
    );
  }
        
    

E/flutter (27438): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, java.lang.IllegalStateException: The Android view returned from PlatformView#getView() was already added to a parent view.
        E/flutter (27438):  at io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformViewsController$1.createForTextureLayer(PlatformViewsController.java:232)
        E/flutter (27438):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.PlatformViewsChannel$1.create(PlatformViewsChannel.java:122)
        E/flutter (27438):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.PlatformViewsChannel$1.onMethodCall(PlatformViewsChannel.java:60)
        E/flutter (27438):  at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:262)
        E/flutter (27438):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:295)
        E/flutter (27438):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0$io-flutter-embedding-engine-dart-DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:319)
        E/flutter (27438):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:12)
        E/flutter (27438):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
        E/flutter (27438):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        E/flutter (27438):  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        E/flutter (27438):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        E/flutter (27438):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7850)
        E/flutter (27438):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        E/flutter (27438):  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        E/flutter (27438):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
        E/flutter (27438): , null, null)
        E/flutter (27438): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:607:7)
        E/flutter (27438): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:167:18)
        E/flutter (27438): <asynchronous suspension>
        E/flutter (27438): #2      TextureAndroidViewController._sendCreateMessage (package:flutter/src/services/platform_views.dart:1134:18)
        E/flutter (27438): <asynchronous suspension>
        E/flutter (27438): #3      AndroidViewController.create (package:flutter/src/services/platform_views.dart:762:5)
        E/flutter (27438): <asynchronous suspension>
        E/flutter (27438): #4      TextureAndroidViewController.setSize (package:flutter/src/services/platform_views.dart:1062:7)
        E/flutter (27438): <asynchronous suspension>
        E/flutter (27438): #5      RenderAndroidView._sizePlatformView (package:flutter/src/rendering/platform_view.dart:179:29)
        E/flutter (27438): <asynchronous suspension>
        E/flutter (27438):
```

Comment: It appears that your Android code is trying to load the same view a second time.  Could you share your code around `PlatformView`?  That may help identify the issue.

Comment: @RyanM i have updated , please check now